# How to call class with dependency injection (DI)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

## Description

I want to create an object of a class with dependency injection. If I set the parameter manually I got the exception `Cannot access a disposed of the object.`.

This Application is a Blazor wasm with Dotnet core 3.1. I´ve created a Middleware that should connect to a query console. So I have a static list that contains all query clients. If a client is missing it will be created.

*Invoke Async in the middleware:*

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    IInstanceControlRepository instanceControlRepository,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _instanceControlRepository = instanceControlRepository;

    long timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
    var instances = _instanceControlRepository.GetAllInstances();

    if (_time + 3 <= timestamp)
    {
        _time = timestamp;

        // Remove
        foreach(var client in TeamspeakInstanceQueryClients.ToList())
        {
            var cl = instances.ToList().Find(el => el.Id == client.Instance.Id);
            
            if(cl == null)
            {
                client.Dispose();
                TeamspeakInstanceQueryClients.RemoveAll(el => el.Instance.Equals(client.Instance));
            }
        }   

        // Create & Update
        foreach (var instance in instances)
        {
            var queryClient = TeamspeakInstanceQueryClients.Find(el => el.Instance.Id == instance.Id);

            if(queryClient == null)
            {
                //var test = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ApplicationDbContext>(serviceProvider);
                //var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                //queryClient = new TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient(new InstancesControlRepository(ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ApplicationDbContext>(serviceProvider)));
                queryClient = new TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient(serviceProvider);
                _ = queryClient.Connect(instance);
                TeamspeakInstanceQueryClients.Add(queryClient);
            }
            else
            {
                _ = queryClient.CheckInstanceData(instance);
            }
        }
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

*TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient.cs*

```
public partial class TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient : ITeamspeakInstanceQueryClient
{
    private IInstanceControlRepository _instanceControlRepository;

    private const short MAX_RETRYS = 3;
    private const short TIME_TO_RETRY = 10;

    private EventHandler OnConnected;

    public Instance Instance { get; internal set; }
    public TeamSpeakClient Client { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; internal set; }
    private short _connectionTrys = 0;

    public TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _instanceControlRepository = new InstancesControlRepository(ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ApplicationDbContext>(serviceProvider));
        Init();
    }
}
```

*InstancesControlRepository.cs*

```
public class InstancesControlRepository : IInstanceControlRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

    public InstancesControlRepository(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
        option.UseMySql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new System.Version(10, 4, 13), ServerType.MariaDb)
        )
    );
    services.AddScoped<IInstanceControlRepository, InstancesControlRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IServerQueryRepository, ServerQueryRepository>();
```

## What I´ve tried

1. I´ve tried to create the class with the service provider but it comes to the same error
2. I´ve tried to create the missing parameters with the service provider in the created class. But I need to inject the service provider which also creates the exception `Cannot access a disposed of the object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.`
3. I´ve tried to make the service provider static so it can´t be disposed but it is disposed.

Comment: Why is your `TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient` class creating an instance of `InstancesControlRepository` instead of simply registering `InstancesControlRepository` in the DI container and letting that deal with initializing types?

Comment: You mean in the ClientFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that instance of `IServiceProvider` is [a scoped one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scoped) and it is disposed when the scope ends (in the end of request I assume). You can try define singleton factory for your `TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient` and  use it:

```
class ClientFactory
{
    private IServiceProvider _sp { get; set; }        
    private IServiceScope _scope  { get; set; }
    public  MyClass(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        _sp = sp;
        _scope = sp.CreateScope();
    }
    public TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient Create() => new TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient(_scope.ServiceProvider);
}

// register it as singleton 
services.AddSingleton<ClientFactory>();
```

and use it in `InvokeAsync`:

```
var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClientFactory>();
queryClient = factory.Create();
```

P.S. this code can be improved vastly and is used only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Looks like it won´t work cause the repository has a EF Dbcontext. I´ve got this error => System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[PhoenixBot.Server.ApplicationDbContext]' from root provider.

Comment: You can create child scope and store it in factory and use it. See updated post. Maybe you will need to create scope per `TeamspeakInstanceQueryClient`, depends on the actual situation.

Comment: Looks like it worked. But just for my information. This factory create a new "lifetime scope container" which create the scoped DI?

Comment: @LukasGund there is concept of scopes. The singleton has the root one build with `services.BuildServiceProvider()`, then it can create scopes - one of the usual scenarios is one per request to web service, every scope will share `Scoped` services (so inside of scope you will always get the same scoped service). When scope ends it disposes all instantiated scoped and transient services implementing `IDIsposable`(in general case, also some other containers can have different behavior).